# You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required

Tags: database, ms-access

I need help for my database.
It's showing me You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required.

[second table][1]
[relationship][3]

``  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8tO2.jpg

'' [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYn98.jpg

Comment: We'd need to see the SQL and the database table layout. But it has to do with referential integrity. E.g. You cannot add a CustomerOrder if the customer is not on file.

Comment: i just add the relationship

Comment: and one of the tables the  other one is

Comment: Isn't the relationship in the wrong direction? One course work can have 0:n Assessments - not the other way around?

Comment: i try to change it but i cant

Comment: it showing me another error

Comment: You should be able to click on the line between the two and delete or edit. If you have data already, you might have to delete some - depends.